# Call an image url from a JSON to tableview file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the data of my WordPress json I have the following:

```
 [
{
id: 11,
title: {
rendered: "My title post"
},
content: {
rendered: "Content text html",
}
_embedded: {
wp:featuredmedia: [
{
source_url: ".../myimage.jpg",
}
]
}
}
```

I have my structures in the file OfertasTableViewCell.swift

```
struct JsonSosTalleres : Codable {
    let id : Int
    let title : Title?
    let content : Content?
    let embedded : Embedded?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case title = "title"
        case content = "content"
        case embedded = "_embedded"
    }

}


struct Title : Codable {
    let rendered : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rendered = "rendered"
    }
}

struct Content : Codable {
    let rendered : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rendered = "rendered"
    }
}


struct Embedded : Codable {
    let featuredmedia : [Featuredmedia]?    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case featuredmedia = "wp:featuredmedia"
    }
}

struct Featuredmedia : Codable {
    let urlimage : String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case urlimage = "source_url"
    }
}
```

For the title is already working, but I have problems to get the url of the image:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        guard let cell = tablaOfertas.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ofertacell") as? OfertasTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.tituloPost.text = getData[indexPath.row].title?.rendered // funciona ok

        cell.imagePost.text = getData[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?.urlimage // error :  Value of type '[Featuredmedia]' has no member 'urlimage'

        return cell

    }
```

Any suggestions why it does not work or how would you call the URL of the image?

With the following code:

```
cell.imagePost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?.urlimage
```

get the following error: *Value of type '[Featuredmedia]' has no member 'urlimage'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`featuredmedia` is an array not a single object , Can you try

```
 cell.imagePost.text = datosOfertas[indexPath.row].embedded?.featuredmedia?[0].urlimage
```